Change Flutter Package Name
I am trying to change the package name of my flutter application.
I have tried all the below packages and they all fail for some reason or another.
They either fail or do not change the namespace and/or applicationId in all the required files.
Has anyone else tried to do this recently (for IOS and Android)?
I tried:

change_app_package_name
package_rename
rename

Most answers I have seen are from years ago.


Update pubspec.yaml: Open your project's pubspec.yaml file. Change the name field to your new package name.
In Android Studio, navigate to android directory in your Flutter project.


Open the build.gradle file.
Update the applicationId in the defaultConfig section.


Manually change


Navigate to android/app/src/main directory.
Open the AndroidManifest.xml file.
Change the package attribute in the  tag.



if you are using VSCode, you just global search and replace the com.example.your_app , for iOS , com.example.yourApp ,  also you may need to change the com.example based on your current name.

@DroidFlutter In step 3, there is no package attribute in that file... should there already  be one or must I create one?

@pmatatias I replaced all occurrences of com.examle.myApp but then the build failed. Have I changed it in more places than I should? i.e. am I only supposed to change it in the android build.gradle and MainActivity.kt only? Thanks.

yes, try to add 

make sure you uninstall the app from your device ( if its already exist before)

Ok thank you... I added a package attribute in AndroidManifest.xml, edited build.gradle, and MainActivity.kt. It seems to be working on my android.
Are there any other steps for ios?

For iOS manually Update :

Navigate to ios/Runner directory.
Open the Info.plist file.
Change the CFBundleIdentifier key.
In xml file...
CFBundleIdentifier
com.example.your_new_package_name
Update Import Statements:
Search for and replace the old package name with the new one throughout your project.


Ok I've implemented the changes and seems to be running fine. Thanks for your help!
